# No permission to create sub directory when user belongs to directory group

Tags: filesystems, directory, solaris

Given a directory DirA (directory owner is `root` and group is `sys`).
Given a user userA, user belongs to group sys, he should be able to make a sub directory inside DirA ?

on Solaris SunOS 5.9 I have a directory `/opt`:

```
bash-2.05$ ls -la /
total 1205
drwxr-xr-x  34 root     root        1024 Mar 17 04:21 .
drwxr-xr-x  34 root     root        1024 Mar 17 04:21 ..
.. Removed all..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     other         16 Apr 14  2008 opt -> /export/home/opt
```

This symbolic link takes me to:

```
bash-2.05$ ls -la /export/home
total 524638
drwxr-xr-x  31 root     root        1024 Jan 25  2015 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     sys          512 Jul  2  2007 ..
...REMOVED...
drwxr-xr-x  12 root     sys          512 Apr 24 10:29 opt
```

I am logged in with user builder:

```
bash-2.05$ /usr/ucb/whoami
builder
```

And he belongs to groups:

```
bash-2.05$ groups builder
other root sys 
bash-2.05$
```

So why `mkdir` fails in `/opt/`?

```
bash-2.05$ cd /opt/
bash-2.05$ pwd
/opt
bash-2.05$ mkdir mynewdir
mkdir: Failed to make directory "mynewdir"; Permission denied
bash-2.05$ cd /export/home/opt/
bash-2.05$ mkdir mynewdir
mkdir: Failed to make directory "mynewdir"; Permission denied
bash-2.05$
```

Comment: The group permissions rwx`r-x`r-x are not permitting to create a dir. for the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
drwxr-xr-x  12 root     sys          512 Apr 24 10:29 opt
```

means that the directory is only writable for `root`. For `sys` group members to be able to make changes to the directory (including creating subdirectories), it needs to be

```
drwxrwxr-x  12 root     sys          512 Apr 24 10:29 opt
```

If you want to enable this:

```
chmod g+w opt
```

will make the appropriate change.